# Importing Max_Error from sklearn.metrics

Tags: python, import

I'm attempting to import max error from sklearn.metrics

```
from sklearn.metrics import max_error
```

However when I receive the following message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-861960ac8e03> in <module>
      1 from sklearn.metrics import explained_variance_score
----> 2 from sklearn.metrics import max_error
      3 from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
      4 from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

ImportError: cannot import name 'max_error' from 'sklearn.metrics' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/__init__.py)
```

Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Check your `sklearn` version? `import sklearn` then `print(sklearn.__version__)`. I'm able to import just fine on sklearn 0.22

Comment: @Toukenize They could also share the contents of their Conda environment.

Comment: I did print(sklearn._version_) and the output was 0.20.3. Is there a easy way to update this?